# Data annotation for enforcing that the value stored in a property of type string should actually be a numeric value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Is there an annotation that allows me to say that the following property must have a numeric value and then I want to specify a range for that value?

```
[DataType.???]
[Range(1990, 2015)]
public string AnniversaryYear { get; set;}
```

There's a reason I need this to be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the use of [Data Annotations Extensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/) that simply extends the data annotations that have into the framework, also look this article that show how to use them: [Introducing Data Annotations Extensions](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/introducing-data-annotations-extensions)

Comment: Meanwhile, I just wrote my custom annotation. Thanks for sharing that page. I will definitely read it when I have some more time.

Comment: Great, yes, those extensions are so useful. Or get your hands dirty and create your own extensions